# How to save SQLite settings such as mode, headers and width so they persist

Tags: sqlite

Every time I start SQLite, I have to re-turn on headers, re-switch to column mode, re-change the separator and/or width. How can I make the settings persist?

**`Repeated Code`**

```
.mode column
.headers on
.separator ','
```

In other words, how can I save the settings so that next time I run SQLite, my preferences are automatically applied?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Create a `.sqliterc` file in your home directory

Ah, finally stumbled upon the answer. You can create a `.sqliterc` (SQLite Run Commands file) in your home directory. Every time you run sqlite, it will load the settings from the rc file.

Here's a quick command line script you can paste in the terminal for some basic settings (edit it to add additional preferences):

```
cat << EOF > ~/.sqliterc
.headers on
.mode column
EOF
```

Answer (score 6):

There are alternative command line options. Something like this:

`alias mysqlite='sqlite3 -column -header -separator ,'`